# VS Code Extension Development Duplicate Results For intellisense/code completion

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am working on an extension for dfdl (https://daffodil.apache.org/docs/dfdl/). The intellisense in the extension is returning duplicate values.  I have been unable to trouble shoot the cause.  The code for my extension is here: https://github.com/rt320/daffodil-extension

[VS Code extension in debug window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMHCX.png)

Some additional background. There are multiple developers working on this project. I worked on the intellisense portion of the project. The originally separate code is here: https://github.com/rt320/vscode-dfdl. In the original intellisense code, the duplication doesn't happen.  After the intellisense code was merged into the larger project, the duplication was introduced.  The original extension.ts file that contains the intellisense code was moved to src/languages/dfdl.ts, but the code was not changed.  It seems like the problem may have something to do with the configuration in the package.json. I was wondering if It might have something to do with "command" definitions for the "*EditorContents"?  Is it possible that CompletionProvider function is called twice? Once for each "*EditorContents" command?

```
"commands": [
  {
    "command": "extension.dfdl-debug.debugEditorContents",
    "title": "Debug File",
    "category": "Daffodil Debug",
    "enablement": "!inDebugMode",
    "icon": "$(debug-alt)"
  },
  {
    "command": "extension.dfdl-debug.runEditorContents",
    "title": "Run File",
    "category": "Daffodil Debug",
    "enablement": "!inDebugMode",
    "icon": "$(play)"
  },
```

Also, I'm not sure how to create the minimal Reproducible Example, since the problem doesn't seem to come from the intellisense code itself.

Comment: Can you set breakpoints in https://github.com/rt320/daffodil-extension/blob/main/src/language/dfdl.ts to debug the extension on each autocompletion item it creates?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @lex li I did try setting breakpoints in dfdl.ts, but there is so much going on behind the scene in the vscode.provideCompletionItems function that I haven't been able to determine anything,  I can see where the behind the scene code is looking at each item to match to the beginning letters typed in the editor, but I can't figure out why the returned results are duplicated.